# Sorting to find maximum values

Tags: excel, max

Here is a sample data table:

```
ID Number   Test Type   Score
001            A         81
001            A         75
001            A         93
001            B         62
001            B         87
001            B         82
002            A         91
002            A         83
002            B         94
002            B         97
```

What I want, in excel, is a return of the maximum score of each test type for each id number so it would look like this...

```
ID Number   Test Type   Score
001            A         93
001            B         87
002            A         91
002            B         97
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: `MAXIFS()` should work also.

Comment: or sort them by the third column descending and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAXIFS().  On your second table, if you have the ID number and Test Types, in the C column you can do:

```
=MAXIFS(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000,$A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000,$B2)
```

Where `Sheet1` is your main table.